# Like to view a single post that be written in a array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a PostService and and BlogPost and like to view a Post with the parameter of a url in my html-Site.

The Service is :

```
export class PostService {

    posts = [
        {
        id: '1',
        title: 'this title',
        url: 'this-title',
        body: 'this body'
        }
    ]
    
    constructor() {
        const local_posts = localStorage.getItem('posts');
        if (local_posts) {
        this.posts = JSON.parse(local_posts);
        } else {
        localStorage.setItem('posts', JSON.stringify(this.posts));
        }
    }
    
    getList() {
        return this.posts;
    }
    
    get(id: string) {
        return { ...this.posts.find(p => p.id === id) };
    }
    
    getBy(url?: string) {
        return { ...this.posts.find(p => p.url === url) };
    }
}
```

And in my BlogPost I have the error:

> > The member "post" implicitly has an "any" type

```
export class BlogPostComponent implements OnInit {

post;   // Here is the problem

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private postService: PostService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.post = this.postService.getBy(params['url'])

        if (!this.post.id) {
            this.router.navigate(['/not-found-page']);
        }
    })

}
}
```

I try to set

```
post = new Array;
```

or

```
post = new Object;
```

But it would not work.

Have you a idea?

I had now add "noImplicitAny": false to the tsconfig.json. But I think that this is only the second way for this problem.

Comment: If you really just want to get rid off the error, you could write `post!: any;`. Yet I would highly recommend to follow the advices of Ibram Reda further below ;-).

Answer (score 1):

define the `BlogPost` intreface

```
export interface BlogPost {
  id:string;
  title: string;
  url:strign;
  body:stiring;
}
```

and define your property as a type of `BlogPost`

```
export class BlogPostComponent implements OnInit {
post?: BlogPost;
//....
}
```

and refactor your service to use the `BlogPost` interface

```
export class PostService {

    posts: BlogPost[] = [
        {
        id: '1',
        title: 'this title',
        url: 'this-title',
        body: 'this body'
        }
    ]
    
    constructor() {
        const local_posts = localStorage.getItem('posts');
        if (local_posts) {
        this. Posts = JSON.parse(local_posts);
        } else {
        localStorage.setItem('posts', JSON.stringify(this.posts));
        }
    }
    
    getList():BlogPost[] {
        return this.posts;
    }
    
    get(id: string) : BlogPost| null {
        return this.posts.find(p => p.id === id);
    }
    
    getBy(url?: string) : BlogPost| null {
        return this.posts.find(p => p.url === url);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are basically right, but as a convention interface-names in Angular should start with an uppercase letter: `export interface Post`. Moreover I find the word `Post` a bit confusing because most developers would immediately think of 'post-request'. So I'd rather go for `BlogPost`.

Comment: @kellermat you are right, i have updated it to `BlogPost`